# Escape SQL parameters in shell pipeline

Tags: sql, shell, sed, awk, escaping

I have this this in my shell script

```
./osmfilter austria-latest.osm --keep="$key=$value" |
./osmconvert - --all-to-nodes --csv="@id @lat @lon @timestamp $key name" --csv-headline |
awk -F "\t" '{if($5 != "" && $6 != "") print "INSERT INTO nodes (name, timestamp, lat, lon, cid) VALUES (\"",$6,"\",\"",$4,"\",",$2,",",$3,","'$cid'");"}' 
> $value.sql
sed -i '1d' $value.sql
```

Now one line of output is ususally something like:

```
INSERT INTO nodes (name, timestamp, lat, lon, cid) VALUES (" OMV "," 2013-06-21T19:46:57Z ", 48.2160931 , 14.2793397 ,2);
```

But if in the Name there is " or ' the SQL Import will fail:

```
INSERT INTO nodes (name, timestamp, lat, lon, cid) VALUES (" "Landkauf" Bund "," 2014-01-04T10:42:33Z ", 46.7899638 , 15.8526000 ,2);
```

Can I tell awk to escape all " inside for example the $6 output?
Doesn't have to be awk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can escape all the `"` with:

```
awk '{gsub("\"", "\\\"", $6)}
```

#### Example

```
$ echo '"Landkauf" Bund' | awk '{gsub("\"", "\\\"")}1'
\"Landkauf\" Bund
```

#### All together

You are currently using

```
awk -F "\t" '{if($5 != "" && $6 != "") print "INSERT INTO nodes (name, timestamp, lat, lon, cid) VALUES (\"",$6,"\",\"",$4,"\",",$2,",",$3,","'$cid'");"}'
```

But can be reformatted as:

```
awk -F "\t" '$5 && $6 {gsub("\"", "\\\"", $6); printf "INSERT INTO nodes (name, timestamp, lat, lon, cid) VALUES (\"%s\", \"%s\", \"%s\", \"%s\", \"%s\");\n", $6, $4, $2, $3, cid}' cid=$cid
```

Because:

- `if($5 != "" && $6 != "")` is equivalent to `$5 && $6`.
- `printf` can give you better control on what you print.
- `$cid` you cannot use a bash variable like that. You have to do use `cid` and give it with `cid=$cid` as in my sample.

Comment: So just like this?

    awk -F "\t" '{if($5 != "" && $6 != "") print "INSERT INTO nodes (name, timestamp, lat, lon, cid) VALUES (\"",gsub("\"", "\\\"", $6),"\",\"",$4,"\",",$2,",",$3,","'$cid'");"}'

Comment: @user638058 see updated answer with further explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use xxd & sed for this. Most utilities have a hard time with special characters like quotes and slashes so replacing a ' with a \' makes for unreadable code. The following command translates your entire input into hex ascii, with one hex char per line. sed then modifies the hex values without worrying about special chars at all. The data is then translated back into text.

```
xxd -ps -c 1 input.txt | sed -e 's/22/5c22/g' -e 's/27/5c27/g' | xxd -r -p
```

Explanation:

- `xxd -ps -c 1` translates an input file into hex codes for ascii, one char per line
- `'s/22/5c22/g'` translates " to \"
- `'s/27/5c27/g'` translates ' to \'
- `xxd -r -p` reverts the hex to text chars and restores the file

Comment: +1.xxd, didn't know I have that. Eliminates a whole class of problems! But does this really solve the OP? Do you need to redirect at the end like `|xxd -r -p > input.txt.fix && mv -f input.txt.fix input.txt` ?